# PHP Javascript dynamic select box

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to load dynamically a second select drop down based on the selection given from the first drop down. I tried from an example given here but can't seem to get it working on my own. The alert input value has changed shows but the input value has changed 2 message does not appear. Original example here: [PHP MYSQL dynamic select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857764/php-mysql-dynamic-select-box?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
    <select id="select1" onchange="createSelect2()">
       <option value="">Select sth</option>
       <option value="1">1st option</option>
       <option value="2">2nd option</option>
       <option value="3">3rd option</option>
    </select>
    <select id="select2" onchange="selectSelect2">
      <option value="">Select from select1 first</option>
    </select>
    <script>
    $('#select1').change(createSelect2);
    $('#select2').change(selectSelect2);
    function createSelect2(){
        alert("The input value has changed.") ;
    var option = $(this).find(':selected').val(),
        dataString = "option="+option;
        if(option != '')
        {
         alert("The input value has changed 2. The new value is: " + option);
        $.ajax({
            type     : 'GET',
            url      : 'http://www.mitilini-trans.gr/demo/test.php',
            data     : dataString,
            dataType : 'JSON',
            cache: false,
            success  : function(data) {          
                var output = '<option value="">Select Sth</option>';            
                $.each(data.data, function(i,s){
                    var newOption = s;

                    output += '<option value="' + newOption + '">' + newOption + '</option>';
                });            
                $('#select2').empty().append(output);
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log("Ajax failed");
            }
        }); 
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("You have to select at least sth");
    }
   }
   function selectSelect2(){
    var option = $(this).find(':selected').val();
    if(option != '')
    {
        alert("You selected: "+option);
    }
    else
    {
        alert("You have to select at least sth");
    }
   }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Because `$(this)` in a function is what? Did you check it?

Comment: I'm not sure. The original example is shown here in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/g3Yqq/2/

Comment: Any errors in developers console?

Comment: Yes from $. Undefined on the line you are suggesting.

Comment: Did you include jquery?

Comment: jsquery had a bad path. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The script seems correct.
You just forgot to add the jQuery library.

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
```